# Python でのValueError: Length mismatchへの対処が分かりません。

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

以下のコードで突然ValueError: Length mismatchが出てきて、対処の方法が分かりません。同じ証券コードを繰り返し取得したからかと思ったのですがそうではなく、昨日までは問題なく動作していたためどこを改善してよいかも不明です。
解決策を教えていただけますでしょうか。

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from pandas_datareader.stooq import StooqDailyReader
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import sys
import matplotlib.dates as mdate


a=[0]
codes=[1301,1332,1333,1352]

codes = sorted(codes)
start = datetime(2021, 4, 1)
end = datetime(2021, 6, 22)

dfc = (
       StooqDailyReader([f'{n}.JP' for n in codes], start, end).read()
       .Close.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
       .set_axis([codes]*len(a), axis=1)
     )

print(dfc)

print(dfc.corr())
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
sns.heatmap(dfc.corr(),annot=True, vmax =1,vmin=-1,cmap ='coolwarm',center =0)
```

以下エラー内容

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-4bb2b2d041c0> in <module>()
     20        StooqDailyReader([f'{n}.JP' for n in codes], start, end).read()
     21        .Close.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
---> 22        .set_axis([codes]*len(a), axis=1)
     23      )
     24 

6 frames
pandas/_libs/properties.pyx in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in set_axis(self, axis, new_labels)
    225         if new_len != old_len:
    226             raise ValueError(
--> 227                 f"Length mismatch: Expected axis has {old_len} elements, new "
    228                 f"values have {new_len} elements"
    229             )

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 3 elements
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 証券コードに重複がある場合(例えば `codes=[1301,1301,1333,1352]` など)、同じ証券コードのデータは一度だけしか取得しませんのでデータフレームの列数が少なくなります。なので、`.set_axis([codes]*len(a), axis=1)` を `.set_axis(list(dict.fromkeys(codes)), axis=1)` に変更してみて下さい。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。試してみたのですが、同様のエラー内容が出てきました。

Comment: 考えられる状況として、存在しない証券コードが `codes` に含まれているのかもしれません。例えば `codes = [1301, 1302, 1332]` として実行すると同様のエラーが発生します(`1302.JP` は存在しません)。

Answer (score 1):

> 証券コードに重複がある場合(例えば `codes=[1301,1301,1333,1352]` など)、同じ証券コードのデータは一度だけしか取得しませんのでデータフレームの列数が少なくなります。

> 考えられる状況として、存在しない証券コードが `codes` に含まれているのかもしれません。例えば `codes = [1301, 1302, 1332]` として実行すると同様のエラーが発生します(`1302.JP` は存在しません)。

証券コードに重複があったり、存在しない証券コードを指定している場合を考慮して書き直してみました。

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
from pandas_datareader.stooq import StooqDailyReader
from datetime import datetime

codes = [1301, 1332, 1333]
## codes = [1301, 1301, 1332, 1333] # 重複
## codes = [1301, 1302, 1332, 1333] # 欠番

codes = sorted(codes)
start = datetime(2021, 6, 1)
end = datetime(2021, 6, 22)

dfc = (
  StooqDailyReader([f'{n}.JP' for n in codes], start, end).read()
  .Close.astype(int).sort_index()
  .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
  .rename(columns=lambda c: re.sub(r'\.JP$', '', c))
)
```

##### 実行結果

- 重複

```
# 1301.JP が重複
codes = [1301, 1301, 1332, 1333]

print(dfc.head())

            1301  1332  1333
2021-06-01  2974   514  2435
2021-06-02  2918   516  2435
2021-06-03  2936   534  2465
2021-06-04  2935   540  2455
2021-06-07  2942   548  2448
```

- 欠番

```
# 1302.JP は存在しない
codes = [1301, 1302, 1332, 1333]

print(dfc.head())

            1301  1332  1333
2021-06-01  2974   514  2435
2021-06-02  2918   516  2435
2021-06-03  2936   534  2465
2021-06-04  2935   540  2455
2021-06-07  2942   548  2448
```

Comment: 回答のコードで解決しました。ありがとうございます。